# New Relic custom metrics don't work

Tags: python, heroku, newrelic

I'm using New Relic, and it works fine. However, when I try to record custom metrics, they do not appear in the custom dashboard I created. It gives the warning, but I'm not sure how to address it.

```
>>> import newrelic
>>> import newrelic.agent
>>> application = newrelic.agent.register_application()
2014-09-18 11:29:21,020 (2/MainThread) newrelic.core.agent INFO - New Relic Python Agent (2.4.0.4)
2014-09-18 11:29:21,021 (2/MainThread) newrelic.core.agent WARNING - The Python Agent is not enabled.
>>> newrelic.agent.record_custom_metric('Custom/Foo', 1.0, application)
```

Comment: You need to register with an API key no?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the newrelic.ini file is correct? You can override it with `heroku config:add NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini`

You need to make sure newrelic agent gets a licence key, either from Heroku ENV VAR or via the ini file

You should try to print the debug logs? 
`heroku config:add NEW_RELIC_LOG_LEVEL=debug`

More information in [NewRelic Heroku](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/hosting-services/python-agent-and-heroku#installing-the-python-agent) support page